# Getter returns undefined TypeScript Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

When i call getter it returns undefined, but when i try to access public field Email, the value is returned properly. That's my code:

```
export class User {
    public static id: number = 0;
    public userId: number;
    public firstName: string;
    public lastName: string;
    public email: string;
    public password: string;
    public phoneNumber: string;

    public get Email(): string {
        return this.email;
    }
    public get Password(): string {
        return this.password;
    }
    constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string, email: string, password: string, phoneNumber: string) {
        this.userId = User.id;
        ++User.id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

```
export class Client extends User {
    constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string, email: string, password: string, phoneNumber: string) {
        super(firstName, lastName, email, password, phoneNumber);
    }   
}
```

```
    getClient(email: string, password: string): Observable<Client | undefined> {
        return this.http.get<Client[]>(this.usersUrl).pipe(
          map(clients => {
            console.log(`${clients[0].Password} ${clients[0].password} ${clients[0].Email} ${clients[0].email}`)
            return clients.find(client => client.Email === email && client.Password === password);
          })
        );
      }
```

The database is simulated by Angular In-memory Web API.
The values that i get from console log in getClient() method are: undefined a undefined a

I tried debugging setting password and email in constructor by calling setter, but it didn't work anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You do not create an instance of `Client` at all.
Adjust your `getClient` method to actually call `new Client` with the response data.

```
getClient(email: string, password: string): Observable<Client | undefined> {
  return this.http.get<Client[]>(this.usersUrl).pipe(
    map((clients) => clients.map(({ firstName, lastName, email, password, phoneNumber }) => new Client(firstName, lastName, email, password, phoneNumber))),
    map((actualClientInstances) => {
      return actualClientInstances.find(client => client.Email === email && client.Password === password);
    }),
  );
}
```

Comment: I have one more question, how should i do this, when i want the attributes to be private ? I have made setters and getters but dont know what to do after.

Comment: Create a new question on SO. Also, while you are at it, keep on trying yourself and tell us in the question what you tried so far and what your expected outcome is.